# Server Side and Client Side MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have started learning `ASP.Net MVC`, I have few questions with regards to `MVC framework` [Client Side or Server Side]. You might find these questions stupid but I am really confused and would like to clear my doubts.

Here it is....

1. `ASP.Net MVC`, is it server side or client side framework?
2. Let's say my controller methods getting data from the `SQL Server`, I convert it into `JSON` and updating the `MVC view`, in this case

A. Is it called as Client side data binding or Server side binding?

B. While retrieving the data from database using controller method, do i get entire HTML along with data in the response or just the data that I have requested for?

3. In `ASP.Net`, lets say I am inserting data in database on button click event and If I am not wrong, in this case it will submit the entire page to the server, how button click event works in `ASP.Net MVC`?
4. I have also read that we can use `Angular.JS` or `knockout.JS` with `ASP.Net MVC`, what purpose `Angular.JS` or `knockout.JS` would solve if we use it with `ASP.Net MVC`?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ASP.Net MVC, is it server side or client side framework?

```
   > MVC - is Model View Controller - its All-in-One
```

> Let's say my controller methods getting data from the SQL Server, I
>   convert it into JSON and updating the MVC view, in this case
>
> Is it called as Client side data binding or Server side binding?

```
> Server side is ALL what you do with C# (In class library/controllers etc)
```

> While retrieving the data from database using controller method, do i
>   get entire HTML along with data in the response or just the data that
>   I have requested for?

```
>If you will use knockout / angular - then you need just get data from server, and data-bind will happen automatically
```

> In ASP.Net, lets say I am inserting data in database on button click
>   event and If I am not wrong, in this case it will submit the entire
>   page to the server, how button click event works in ASP.Net MVC?

```
>Or with submit form (to action url) - or with client framework (knockout/angular) - you just send json
```

> I have also read that we can use Angular.JS or knockout.JS with
>   ASP.Net MVC, what purpose Angular.JS or knockout.JS would solve if we
>   use it with ASP.Net MVC?

```
>Angular more rich framework. In knockout we have only data-bind with html. It depends on what you need for your project.
```

Answer (score 4):

1. ASP.Net MVC is a server side framework. (An alternative is ASP.Net WebForms: your events are posts to the same page, abstracted to seem like desktop application events.)
2. If you want, you can output data as JSON or XML and use this with a client side JavaScript framework to update your views.
3. You will not have button clicks in ASP.Net MVC. All data is sent to the server as parameters in the URL, GET or POST variables (in truth, WebForms also does this). You can grab the values directly from the Request or use the bindings from MVC to get the values as action parameters.
4. These frameworks are used to build the views in the client side. To use them, you will have to, mostly, output JSON from your controllers.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is a design pattern that you can apply "anywhere" - e.g. server or client side. In ASP.NET MVC, the MVC pattern (model, view, controller) is first and foremost applied server-side, e.g. the code you write executes on the server. (In your view, you can if you like also utilize some MV* pattern, using your own code or a library like Knockout or Angular. This (JavaScript) is then executed on the client, hence client-side.)

Sometimes a piece of code or software that communicates with some other service or similar is labeled a "client", but that is a different context.

Your binding example would execute on the server, if we're talking about ASP.NET MVC `Controller` code. (In general, there is no need from the framework point-of-view to do any explicit JSON conversion, but that's a different question.)

ASP.NET MVC features something called "model binding" (google it). It's there out-of-the-box, but you can control it with your own implementations as well. Thanks to this feature, you normally deal with strongly typed data inside your `Controller`.

ASP.NET MVC and Web Forms are fundamentally different. Explaining exactly how, and how to make buttons in ASP.NET MVC that send data is out of scope, but generally we're talking simple POSTed data, e.g. from an HTML form or whatever.